# Anything wrong with this code?

Tags: iphone

I am using this to determine which view to go to next, from the result as input from UITableView. The following code isn't working, but I think it should be!

Do you see anything wrong with it?

```
NSString *option = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


if (option == @"New Transaction"){

      NTItems *nTItemsController = [[NTItems alloc] initWithNibName:@"NTItems" bundle:nil]; 
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:nTItemsController animated:YES];
      [NTItems release];
} else if ([option isEqualToString:@"Previous Transactions"]){
} else if ([option isEqualToString:@"Reprint a reciept"]){
} else if ([option isEqualToString:@"Settings"]){
} else if ([option isEqualToString:@"Logout"]){
             LoginViewController *nTItemsController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];  
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:nTItemsController animated:YES];
             [nTIemsController release];    

}
```

Each item/object is defined as follows:

```
[menuArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      NSLocalizedString(@"Logout", @"Logout"), @"title",
                      nil,
                      nil]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If menuArray contains dictionaries, you can get to the title key in the current option like this:

```
NSDictionary *option = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *optionTitle = [option objectForKey:@"title"];

if ([optionTitle isEqualToString:@"New Transaction"]) {     
    NTItems *nTItemsController = [[NTItems alloc] initWithNibName:@"NTItems" bundle:nil]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nTItemsController animated:YES];
    [nTItemsController release];
}
else if ([optionTitle isEqualToString:@"Previous Transactions"]) {
} 
else if ([optionTitle isEqualToString:@"Reprint a reciept"]) {
} 
else if ([optionTitle isEqualToString:@"Settings"]) {
} 
else if ([optionTitle isEqualToString:@"Logout"]) {
    LoginViewController *nTItemsController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nTItemsController animated:YES];
    [nTItemsController release];    
}
```

By the way, "receipt" is spelled wrong in "Reprint a reciept".

Answer (score 2):

You are releasing a *class object*, not your instances of the clases: that's a really bad idea (you want `[nTItemsController release]`). Secondly, you are comparing a string by memory address: you are most likely looking for the `-isEqual:` or the `-isEqualToString:` method. Besides that, though, it looks fine.

(I hope that your code is indented/formatted better in the actual file...usually you want to indent and not end your curly braces on the end of the last line in the block...etc.)

Comment: I get our favourite: "unrecognized selector sent to instance" on NSCFDictionary isEqualToString: now. Thanks for correcting the class object issue :)

Comment: That means that `option` is not a string, but an `NSDictionary`. Does your `menuArray` contain dictionaries?

Comment: Check amendement, I am using dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Using "isEqualToString" to compare the NSString, and the "release" method message should send to a instance but the class object.

Comment: I get our favourite: "unrecognized selector sent to instance" on NSCFDictionary isEqualToString: now. Thanks for correcting the class object issue :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSString *option = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSAssert([option isKindOfClass [NSString class]], @"Expecting an NSString here!");

if ([option isEqualToString:@"New Transaction"]){

      NTItems *nTItemsController = [[NTItems alloc] initWithNibName:@"NTItems" bundle:nil]; 
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:nTItemsController animated:YES];
      [nTItemsController release];
} else if ([option isEqualToString:@"Previous Transactions"]){
} else if ([option isEqualToString:@"Reprint a reciept"]){
} else if ([option isEqualToString:@"Settings"]){
} else if ([option isEqualToString:@"Logout"]){
             LoginViewController *nTItemsController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];  
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:nTItemsController animated:YES];
             [nTIemsController release];    

}
```